# Does non-orthogonality of joint states follow from non-orthogonality of ALL marginals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Suppose we have a composite system $AB$ and we are considering two joint (pure) states
$$
\psi,\psi^\prime \in \mathcal{H}_{AB} .
$$
Let's define the reduced or marginal states of $A$ and $B$ in the usual way, so $\rho_A = \mathrm{Tr}_B (|\psi><\psi|)$, $\rho^\prime_A = \mathrm{Tr}_B (|\psi^\prime><\psi^\prime|)$, $\rho_B = \mathrm{Tr}_A (|\psi><\psi|)$, and $\rho^\prime_B = \mathrm{Tr}_A (|\psi^\prime><\psi^\prime|)$.

Suppose that all we know is:

(1) the $A$-marginal states $\rho_A$ and $\rho^\prime_A$ are non-orthgonal, by which I mean their fidelity is greater than zero $F(\rho_A, \rho^\prime_A)>0$, which in turn holds iff $\text{supp}(\rho_A) \not\perp \text{supp}(\rho_A^\prime)$.

(2) the $B$-marginal states $\rho_B$ and $\rho^\prime_B$ are not only non-orthogonal, but also identical: $\rho_B = \rho^\prime_B$. (This is in turn equivalent to $F(\rho_B,\rho^\prime_B)=1$.)

**My question is: Does it follow from (1) and (2) that the joint states $\psi$ and $\psi^\prime$ must be non-orthogonal, too?**

(If the answer to the above is yes, then we may also ask what happens when we weaken (2) so as to no longer assume identity.)

Note: I am aware that the non-orthogonality of one marginal does not imply the non-orthogonality of the composite. The interesting question, from my perspective, is does the non-orthogonality of *all* marginals imply this?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding you, a counterexample to your conjecture would be any pair of bell states, for example $\vert 00 \rangle + \vert 11 \rangle$ and $\vert 00 \rangle - \vert 11 \rangle$, which are orthogonal but have identical marginals.

Comment: @JoelKlassen That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. The simplest counterexample is any pair of Bell states, for example  $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\vert 00 \rangle + \vert 11 \rangle \right) \textrm{ and } \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\vert 00 \rangle - \vert 11 \rangle \right)$$
These two states have identical marginals, namely the maximally mixed states. However they are orthogonal.